# How add Cart price rules on my conditions

Tags: shipping, dropshipping

you can help me settings cart rules on my conditions:
When the amount in the cart reaches a certain value, then 1 .... 000 included free shipping. because i not know how can right now add rules on this requirement

Please help me if you have time

Very Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want free shipping when order amount exceeds a certain amount?

Comment: Yes Sir, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who still want to use a shopping cart price rule (maybe they want to add some additional conditions except cart amount).

When editing the rule, inside the **Conditions** tab set the requirements (for example, Shopping cart subtotal equals or grater than ...)

[image: shopping cart price rule conditions]

And under the **Actions** tab, you have the **Free Shipping** yes/no dropdown. You only need to set that to yes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. You don't want to use shopping cart rule. It can be done within shipping method.

Go to admin -> System -> Configuration -> (Under Sales)Shipping Methods -> Free Shipping -> Fill **Minimum Order Amount** field with your amount you wish ..